# Не работает curl_init на Kali Linux (debian)

Tags: php, linux, curl

Вот код который пытаюсь запустить

```
$curl = curl_init(); // init

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site.com");

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Comment: и что в нем не работает?

Comment: @Etki добавил ошибку

Comment: А у вас PHP с поддержкой curl собран?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Не знаю как это проверить, я не нашел в директории /etc/php5 никаких конфигураций по curl.

Comment: phpinfo возможно покажет. Но если вы не уверены что PHP собран с curl - смотрите в эту сторону.

Comment: @modelfak, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `dpkg --get-selections | grep curl`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin
`curl      install
curlftpfs     install
libcurl3:amd64     install
libcurl3-gnutls:amd64    install
python-pycurl     install`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в какую?

Comment: В сторону наличия curl в PHP, вестимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит забывать, что не все программное обеспечение идет out of the box, и его иногда все-таки надо устанавливать

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl
```

Comment: Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет php5-curl

Comment: `apt-get update` и не забыть добавить необходимые рпозитории, если их нет

Comment: И такая же реакция на `apt-get install  php5-curl`

Comment: Как добавить репозиторий?

Comment: @modelfak, http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories